# iOS UISegmentedControl with image overlaps by tint color

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

I have some problem with UISegmentedControl with image. When I put image with text on it in segment tintcolor paints my image and the text.
Can any help with it?

setting up UIImage in Segment

```
UIImage *tmp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UISegmentedControl-active"];
    UIImage *imageWithText = [UIImage imageFromImage:tmp string:@"20" color:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:imageWithText forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

imageFromImage code:

```
+ (id) imageFromImage:(UIImage*)image string:(NSString*)string color:(UIColor*)color
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    CGSize expectedTextSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    int width = image.size.width + 5;
    int height = MAX(expectedTextSize.height, image.size.width);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake((float)width, (float)height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    int fontTopPosition = (height - expectedTextSize.height) / 2;
    CGPoint textPoint = CGPointMake(width + 5, fontTopPosition);


    // Images upside down so flip them
    //CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, size.height);
    //CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){ {0, (height - image.size.height) / 2}, {image.size.width, image.size.height} }, [image CGImage]);
    [string drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Image goes blue(default tintcolor).

Anyway, if anyone know how to do segmented control with circular(not rounded) segments(buttons), offer your solution.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Add Some code or image. In your question. so we can understand, what you try to Do with UISegmentedControl.

Comment: EnriMR, sorry, but i can't post images

Comment: @mut you need to change the tint color.. which you want for your image. I think it's is not possible to keep image color as it is.

Comment: @AshokLondhe tint color paints text on image. So I don't see the text